# selection of customer who placed order in particular year

Tags: sql, selection

i want to do this

> Display the Customer Name of all customers who have placed orders in 1996

and i use for this

```
select
  Customers.ContactName 
from Customers
where 
  Customers.CustomerID = (
    select Orders.CustomerID 
    from Orders 
    where year(Orders.OrderDate)=1996
  );
```

but it gives an error.

The database is Northwind

Comment: The error is likely that you are returning multiple rows from the subquery?  Use `WHERE Customers.CustomID IN (select....)` instead of `Customers.CustomerId = (select...)`

Comment: yes Michael this is the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine your subquery is returning multiple results try this (note the IN):

```
select
  Customers.ContactName 
from Customers
where 
  Customers.CustomerID IN (
    select Orders.CustomerID 
    from Orders 
    where year(Orders.OrderDate)=1996
  );
```

Comment: +1 . . . You explain the problem and fix it in the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

try it with join like this

```
SELECT
    c.ContactName
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o
    ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerId
WHERE YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 1996
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.contactName -- DISTINCT because some customers might have multiple orders
FROM customers c
JOIN orders o
    ON o.customerId = c.customerId
    AND year(o.orderDate) = 1996
```

In order to compare subqueries to scalars, you need to ensure that the subquery returns exactly one result (e. g. by using SELECT TOP 1 ... or SELECT COUNT(*) ...). Alternatively, you can check that the subQuery has rows using EXISTS or check for containment with IN. However, JOINs are often the preferred method for this kind of query, as in some cases the database appears to better optimize them.